# How to disply timdstamp column with specific format in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA and I have a table like below:

```
public class Apk {

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column
  private java.util.Date creationTime;

}
```

My DBMS is MySQL5.x and the above column is defined datetime type in it. I just call findAl() method in a repository class extends PaginAndSortingRepository.

```
public interface ApksRepository extends PaginAndSortingRepository<Apk, Long>{

}


public class ApksServiceImpl implements ApksService {

    public PagingRes<Apk> findAll(PageInfo pageInfo){
        PaginRes<Apk> result = new PagingRes<Apk>();

        Page page = apksRepos.findAll(pageInfo.toPageRequest());
        result.fromPage(page);

        return result;
    }
}

public class PageInfo {

  private int page;
  private int rp;
  private String sortname;
  private String sortorder;
  private String query;
  private String qtype;

  //getters and setters

  public PageRequest toPageRequest() {

     Sort.Direction direction = Sort.Direction.ASC;
     if (sortorder!=null && "DESC".equals(sortorder))
         direction = Sort.Direction.DESC;
     return new PageRequest(page-1, rp, direction, sortname);
  }
}


public class PagingRes<T> {

   private long total;
   private int page;
   private int rowPerPage;
   private List<T> rows;

   //getters and setters

   public PagingRes<T> fromPage(Page page) {
       this.page = page.getNumber();
       this.rowPerPage = page.getSize();
       this.total = page.getTotalElements();
       this.rows = page.getCotent();
       return this;
   }
}
```

And I am trying to display data in the table including the column but when I did it, the column is shown as long type. I wan to display the column in the fomat 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'. How can I do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If your field is saved in the database with a datetime type, then maybe you need to check your mysql client to do a query where it casts the column to a human readable format.

Comment: When I see the data from the server in the firebug, the field is given to the client as long type. But I queried in mysql console, I can see the field as human readable datetime foramt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew that Jackson mapper for JSON response were giving weird result. So after searching, I used JsonSerializer to fix it like below:

```
Entity class

              @JsonSerialize(using=AuDateSerializer.class)  
              private java.util.Date eventTime;




Custom Serializer
              public class AuDateSerializerextends JsonSerializer<Date> {
              @Override
              public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                jgen.writeString(formatter.format(value));
              }
            }
```

Now it works fine. Thanks.